# async / await and Task / Wait in C# the same?

Tags: c#, task, async-await

I learned to use `Task` easily than `async`/`await`. Now, I'm trying to use `Task` to learn `async`/`await`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        //Magic1(); 
        Magic2();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static async void Magic1()
    {
        var taskA = GetDataAsync();
        var taskB = GetDataAsync();
        var taskC = GetDataAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("a: " + await taskA);
        Console.WriteLine("b: " + await taskB);
        Console.WriteLine("c: " + await taskC);
    }

    static Task Magic2()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var taskA = GetDataAsync();
            var taskB = GetDataAsync();
            var taskC = GetDataAsync();

            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { taskA, taskB, taskC });

            Console.WriteLine("a: " + taskA.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("b: " + taskB.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("c: " + taskC.Result);
        });
    }

    static Task<string> GetDataAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
            }
            var endTime = DateTime.Now;
            return startTime.ToString() + " to " + endTime.ToString() + " is " + (endTime - startTime).ToString();
        });
    }
```

I created two methods that appears to do the same thing, my questions are:

1) is `Magic1` and `Magic2` the same under the hood?

2) if they are not the same, can I convert `Magic1` to a method that does the same thing without using `async` and `await` keywords?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "can I convert Magic1` to a method that uses Task instead. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry, I mean without using async and await keywords, is it possible for me to write the same method that does the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, I'm trying to use my knowledge in Task to learn async/await.

I really recommend you *not* do this. Although task-based parallelism (.NET 4.0) and the task-based asynchronous pattern (`async`/`await`) use the same type (`Task`), they are completely different. They solve different problems and have a different way of working.

Instead, I suggest you pretend that you know nothing about the `Task` type and start with my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). At the end of my `async` intro are several followup resources, including the MSDN docs which are quite good for this feature.

If you're really familiar with continuations, you can (mostly) think of `await` as meaning "rewrite the rest of this method as a continuation and schedule it using the current `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`". But even that is only an approximation; there are plenty of edge cases. It is not at all the same as doing a `Task.Wait[All]` within a `Task.Run`.

Comment: I was actually reading your blog before I asked my question. :) I'll read it again.

Answer (score 1):

Differences between the two methods:

- **Where their code runs**. Magic2 will run on the threadpool instead of in the caller's synchronization context, because you (unnecessarily) used Task.Run. If you were writing UI code, this could cause Magic2 to fail.
- **Blocking**. Magic1 blocks the caller until it is done. This is generally a mistake when writing async code. Magic2 won't block the caller, even if you remove the Task.Run.
- **Incremental work**. If taskB takes significantly longer to complete, that won't delay Magic2 from printing the result of taskA. Magic1 waits for all three tasks to finish, so it won't print taskA until after taskB finished.

Comment: When you say "Magic1 blocks the caller until it is done", do you mean the `Main` method will not execute any code until `Magic1` is done?

Comment: That's exactly what he means. To make it non blocking, have it return a `Task`. Maybe use `Task.WhenAll`.